# qemu: emulated nic is too fast

Tags: linux, network-adapter, qemu, throughput

On archlinux, I started a VM with qemu emulating a rtl8139 network card by giving it the following parameters:

```
-device rtl8139,id=nic0,netdev=tap0 -netdev tap,id=tap0,ifname=tap0
```

After booting the machine, I measured network connectivity using the iperf3 utility which showed a bandwidth of 1.5 Gbit/s. I'm puzzled by this result, because according to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Devices/Network the rtl8139 should only do 10/100 Mbit/s. Is the information given on that site wrong?

Comment: Are you testing iperf3 from host to guest or viceversa? That will fake the result with host <> guest communication performance.